# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

$dob = $_SESSION['dob'];
$month = $_SESSION['month'];
$s = $_POST['present'];
$p = "1";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE atten SET total = ? WHERE name = ?")) 
{
    // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
    foreach ($s as $name) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $p, $name);

        // Execute the statement.
        $stmt->execute(); 
    }

    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting when I try to execute the above code:

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You did not initialize $mysqli

Comment: where $mysqli is defined?

Comment: You probably forgot to `include` the file where database `$mysqli` connection is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the `mysqli` object before you can use it

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$mysqli->prepare('SQL STATEMENT');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to **create a database connection** and then only you can make queries from the database. like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Example #1 here on how to create a mysqli object:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php